# Unresponsive Recruiter after accepting the offer

Tags: new-job

So I got an offer from well known mid size company last October. I am suppose to join the company at the end of this month. I have been trying to contact my recruiter for the past one week and I haven't received any response for her, which is unlike her because she usually responses pretty quickly. So I went on her LinkedIn and saw that she actually had left the company last month. I was very worried because I didn't have any other person's contact information from the company, neither did I have HR's or the hiring mangers. So I decided to call one of my friends who works at the company  and he gave me the general HR email address for the company. So now I am wondering should I email the general HR's email? or does it look bad that I got the HR email internally through one of the employees.

Also after digging around a little bit, I found this other recruiter's email that my recruiter told me contact in case of an emergency when she was leaving on her vacation back in August. So it is better to contact this recruiter or contact HR? (I have never spoken to this recruiter before)

I am also a bit worried that the company may have taken the offer back. How likely is this? They have also completed a background check on me.

Thank you

Comment: How has it taken more than 4 months to get to this point, where you are only joining the company, after all this time?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for being blunt here: PICK UP THE PHONE.

Call the company's front desk and ask to speak (in that order)

1. Hiring Manager (name should be on the offer letter)
2. Any person in HR or recruiting which name you can remember, starting with the emergency contact
3. Any person whose name is mentioned on the offer letter
4. General HR contact

This is a bizarre situation. You need to resolve this quickly, if you want to actually salvage the job. E-mail is too slow and too easy to just ignore. Your first priority is to find the right contact and this is much quicker by phone. Be prepared to get transferred a few times, but make sure you write down the name of everyone you talk to.

Comment: I agree it's weird. You had an interview with only the recruiter? Not someone whose department you'll be joining? You got an offer without knowing who you will be working for?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear if your "recruiter" is internal (works at the same company which you will work for) or external (works for company X and you will do work for company Y).

I would first cold call the emergency contact you were given. Explain it to that person.

If you get voice mail or would rather use email, just say that you have an offer letter but you lost contact with 'recruiter Z' and are trying to reach her about accepting the offer.

If that doesn't work you can use the general HR email that you have.
You have an offer to work for them, they should be aware of you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately, I don't have the emergency contact's phone number, I just have her email, so I will email her. Actually, do you think it would be fine to email the HR first? So I can maybe get a faster response?

Comment: You would be a better judge of that - I don't have enough details.  You could send the email to both of them if you wanted to, or send to one and copy the other.  Don't send to both if those are two different companies.

Answer (score 0):

If the recruiter was external, I'd try and contact that someone at her former firm.  I'd try both the phone and email.  I would give them 24 hours to responds, at which point I'd reach out to HR at the firm you were joining.

You should use the phone when contacting both firms (but send emails also).  Emails can get lost.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have anyone's phone number. Do you think it would be okay if I contacted HR first? So maybe I can get a faster response?

Comment: Does the recruiting firm have a website?  There must be a contact number.  But sure, contact HR. This isn't your fault and won't be understood as such.